# Search for a multiple line string in multiple files and give the next string out

Tags: python, full-text-search

I try to learn python by working on projects I really would like to have.
Now I'm at a point where I don't know how to solve it.

I want to search through a file and want lo list all the strings which stand behind an indicator string which also can variate.

Therefore, I need to search for a multiple line string with an unknown number of tabs between the strings and would like to know the string after this (multiple times in a file)

```
    solution.append(
        base.fresher(
            current = indicator_var,
            nominal = unknown_value,
            comment = "comment XYZ"
        )
    )

#comment

    solution.append(
        base.fresher(
            current = indicator_var,
            nominal = unknown_value,
            comment = "comment ABCDEFG"
        )
    )
```

"   Base.fresher(    current = indicater_var" is something I would like to search. But here I have the problem that I don't know how many tabs are between the "Base.fresher(" and "current = indicater_var". This can varriate.
And how should I proceed after I found it, how do I get the "unknown_value". And this multiple times in one file.

Actually I have no code to show you. I tried it so many times that the result was an unreadable piece of code which is even more confusing.

This is all I have right know:

```
your_search_word = "base.fresher("

file = open("test_file.txt", "r")


for line in file:
    splitted = line.split("\n")
    variables.append(splitted)

your_string = variables
list_of_words = your_string.split()

next_word = list_of_words[list_of_words.index(your_search_word) + 1]

print(next_word)
```

I had a little success with part of this code a few days ago, so I'm clinging to it, but I also know I have no idea how to get anywhere here.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = []
your_search_word = "base.fresher("
with open("test_file.txt", "r") as f:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if found:
             words.append(line)
        elif your_search_word == line
             found = True
```

Notes:

- with open is maybe safer, because you don't have to close the file and therefore can't forget.
- I used strip() to get rid of the newlines
- we set a variable to True when a line equals the searchwords
- we only add lines to our list 'words' when the found variable is True

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond!

I changed:
 elif your_search_word == line:
And it seams to work.

But know there is a huge list with stuff in it. But I will check that first. 
Also right now we just searched for one line.

Comment: I also edited the answer to replace = with ==. I think you need also a stop-condition. When a line equals a certain string, then found should be set to False again. Then only when the begin-condition is true, found will be True and lines will be added again.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of nessuno I made a few changes (remove "=" and ",")

```
words = []
your_search_word = "current = indicator_var,"

with open("test_file.txt", "r") as f:
    found = False
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if found:
             words.append(line.split("= ")[1].split(",")[0])
             found = False
        elif your_search_word == line:
             found = True
print(words)
```

---

```
['unknown_value', 'unknown_value']
```

This is not the final solution but I have to work on it for a while and post my results here.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Peon, welcome to the stack! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you've haven't done so already. Please refrain from posting this kind of progress update as an answer. We are a question-and-answer forum, so answers should be wholesale solutions, rather than iterations of the problem-solving process. It would be more appropriate to comment on nessuno's answer.